# Set group owner to individual or another group?

Tags: groups, intranet

I am working on creating an intranet for a company where I have each project be a group and inside that group there are smaller groups that are more specific. The project group is owned by a project lead group that will also have control over the project subsite. My question is who should own the project lead group, another group that is composed of all the project leads or have the actual project lead be the owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a Group it will be easier to add more users as well as remove users.

So I would prefer to use Group instead of a single user.

For example, Member group owner can be set to Owners group.

Comment: When does the hierarchy eventually end? It seems like there should always be a group owning another group, who will own the top most group then?

Comment: You can use Site Collection Administrator. Also I believe Top most site will have a Site Owners Group, you can also use that

Comment: Ahh that makes sense.